# xinput list "UNKNOWN"

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, xinput, touch-screen, libinput

I posted this question is Ask Ubuntu but nobody was able to answer it, it seems like. I am including it here because this does not appear to be an Ubuntu-specific problem: This is a modified version of that question

On the One Netbook 3s, the active stylus either does not work at all or behaves strangely depending on the kernel version used (tested in Ubuntu and Manjaro. Distribution makes no difference. Only the kernel version does).

The following is the output of xinput list on newer versions of the linux kernel. I.e. any versions newer than 18.04.2:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD Mouse        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GXTP7386:00 27C6:0113 UNKNOWN             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GXTP7386:00 27C6:0113                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD Wireless Radio Control   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GXTP7386:00 27C6:0113 Keyboard            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD System Control   id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Behavior: The stylus acts like it is "clicking" continuously, similar to the problem observed on the One Netbook 2s and 1s with the Goodix touchscreen as documented and fixed here: https://gitlab.com/AdyaAdya/goodix-touchscreen-linux-driver

However the issue is likely different for two reasons: first of all there are non of the error messages as seen in the case of the 2s model and second of all the touchscreen and stylus do not share an ID. I know that the device 16 should be the Pen by looking at libinput whereas the device with id 15 is indeed the touchscreen (since I can use that to fix the mapping with xinput map-to-output).

Behavior on 18.04.2 kernel: in this Linux version the xinput is exactly the same except instead of "UNKNOWN" we have something to with "Pen pen(0)". Behavior in this case: the stylus *sometimes* is not detected at all but is sometimes detected, especially if a bluetooth connection is made. after that, the stylus "clicks" ones when near the screen. And the buttons act like a totally normal stylus. The stylus is, however, extremely slow.

The pen does not work at all on anything older than 18.04.2 although it does at least show up as a pen on xinput.

Comment: I find it odd you're mentioning an Ubuntu version in place of a kernel version. [Latest stable kernel as of writing the words is 5.6.X](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.6). Did you try it?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer own that computer so I can't test the absolute latest kernel.

However, when I had this computer I did test it with the latest kernels and they all worked *less* well than the older kernels. Basically Ubuntu version 18.04.2 was the only thing that even worked remotely well. Newer versions didn't work as well. I assume the newer versions came with newer kernels but like I said I can't actually test it.